# Can a window's console application be deployed via ClickOnce?

Tags: windows, console-application, clickonce

A very simple question I couldn't find an answer.

Can a windows's console application (an application without a GUI) be deployed via ClickOnce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

There is no difference for ClickOnce if you want to publish an application with GUI (Winforms, WPF) or without (Console Application).